# How can I ignore some columns in eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I Have 38 columns in one table, how can I ignore 3 of 38 columns while select query (Eloquent)?

`Model::where('type',1)->select('id','title',..etc ....)->get();`

the above select may lengthy, is there any solution to ignore the specific 3 and get all rest 35 from my table ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an exception in select query, but you can hide it using eloquent `$hidden` property.  In example:

```
class User extends Model
{

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'another_hidden_column',
    ];
 }
```